# Batch file image rename

Tags: rename, batch-processing

I am a real rookie without any programming knowledge :-)
My task is I can't solve is that I have a lot of pictures in a folder and I need to rename them. I have an excel sheet with the old and new file names in it. The old and new file names don't have any clue.
How can I do that with a powershell script?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? SO focusses mainly on questions regarding specific coding issues

Answer (score 0):

As ever, some representative sample data would be useful.

Here's a basic batch file (standard batch, not power-whatever)

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "?:\directory\where\your\pictures\are\stored
for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a in ("?:\some\directoryname\file.csv") do ECHO(ren "%%~a" "%%~b"
popd
```

Copy-paste using `notepad` or a real text editor - not WORD - into a file called *whateveryoulike*.bat where you can't like `ren` or `rename` (they're reserved words).

Create a file called '?:\some\directoryname\file.csv' from `excel` (export to csv format) using commas as separators then run the batch file by simply entering *whateveryoulike* at the prompt.

As I'e posted it, the `ren` commands to rename the files *from to* will be sent to the console. If these appear correct, change `ECHO(ren` to `ren` to rename rather than report (safety measure to avoid damage if something's amiss)

Note that the `PUSHD` command here will change to the target directory. You can omit this line and it's companion `popd` and the resultant batch will then execute in the "current directory".

This all assumes that your data is of the form

```
oldname.jpg newname.jpg
```

but you haven't shown us that. If it isn;t, this scheme will need adjustment.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I've tried doing my best, as you explained but the result is the following error message. Could you please help me go futher? Thank you! PS H:\képek\teszt> @echo off
setlocal
pushd "?:\képek\teszt
for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a in ("?\képek\teszt\nevek.csv") do ECHO(ren "%%~a" "%%~b"
popd
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@ec
ho' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expressi
on use '$echo'.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: The string starting:
At line:4 char:96
+ for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a in ("?\képek\teszt\nevek.csv") do ECHO(ren "%
%~a" "%%~b <<<< "
is missing the terminator: ".
At line:5 char:5

Comment: This is a batch program. It needs to be run from the command prompt. Nothing to do with powershell.

Comment: The all data I have is only two coloumns of an excel sheet. The current file name and the new file name. I can convert it to any usable form.

Comment: Insuffient information, I'm afraid. Does your new/old filename include the directory or not? "Filename" can mean both. The `ren` command renames a file from `filenameincludingpath` to `namewithnopath` and if the path is omitted, assumes the current directory. To save from excel(2010) use File save as and select CSV(MSDOS) - but still don't know what form your filenames take, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry. The file name doesn't include the directory.

Comment: It seems to be working at last! Tomorrow I'll check it in real.

Comment: Thank You very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Powershell. You would first make sure your CSV file was formatted like:

```
OldFile,NewFile
sample1.jpg,newname1.jpg
sample2.jpg,newname2.jpg
sample3.jpg,newname3.jpg
```

*Note that it's important to put in the header line

Then in a Powershell prompt you could type in these 2 lines and be done:

```
$filesToRename = Import-CSV C:\sample\rename.csv
foreach ($file In $filesToRename) {Rename-Item $file.OldFile $file.NewFile}
```

*Note if the filenames in the CSV file don't include the full file path (if they are just a file name) then make sure you change your working directory to where the files are.

Comment: Thank you! the problem already sold, but this way is very useful for me, because I've just decided to look after a little this powershell thing. Do you have any suggestion where should i start learning?

Comment: I might recommend searching for Hey Scripting Guy and reading that blog, it's by the Microsoft Scripting Guys. Just play around with cmdlets, test things out and learn how they work, don't forget to use Get-Help, happy scripting.